# quite strange things going on with [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in

Tags: php, file-get-contents

Every help would be great on this very strange error!

I´m looping through the files of a directory to detect their MIME-Types. All of them, EXCEPT one, throw the following errors:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(3g.jpg) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Library/WebServer/Documents/V10/getfiles.php on line 46

Warning: file_get_contents(4g.jpg) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Library/WebServer/Documents/V10/getfiles.php on line 46
```

One file, "1g.jpg" works without problems! I´ve renamed them, it´s not the content, it´s the filename, OR, I suppose, the fact, that it´s the first one.
I´ve also checked file permissions, but since renaming does the trick that´s not an explanation either of course.

Here´s the complete code
 (which works fine in another directory as well):

```
$handle=opendir ($dir);
$Previews_php=array();
while ($file = readdir ($handle)) {
    $file_info = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);  // object oriented approach!
    $mime_type = $file_info->buffer(file_get_contents($file));  // e.g. gives "image/jpeg"
    if (preg_match("/image/",$mime_type,$out)) {
        $Bilder_php[]= $file;
    }
}    
closedir($handle);
```

Does anyone have any clue what the problem might be?

Thanks very much!

Comment: do you've checked what $file is containing in each iteration?

Answer (score 0):

I see you're keen on using object oriented approach, so first of all I'd suggest using a DirectoryIterator class, which will allow you to nicely detect whether the "file" you just loaded isn't a dot ("." or "..") or a directory.

```
$images   = array();
$dirName  = dirname(__FILE__) . '/images';   // substitute with your directory
$handle   = new DirectoryIterator($dirName);
$fileInfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);        // move "new finfo" outside of the loop;
                                             // you only need to instantiate it once
foreach ($handle as $fi) {

    // ignore the '.', '..' and other directories
    if ($fi->isFile()) {                    

        // remember to add $dirName here, as filename will only contain 
        // the name of the file, not the actual path
        $path     = $dirName . '/' . $fi->getFilename();


        $mimeType = $fileInfo->buffer(file_get_contents($path)); 

        if (strpos($mimeType, 'image') === 0) { // you don't need a regex here, 
                                                // strpos should be enough.
            $images[] = $path;
        }

    }
}
```

Hope this helps.